# Registry Watcher C#

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, event-handling, registry

I'm a newbie to WMI and I need to implement [RegistryValueChangeEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393042(VS.85).aspx) in a C# service.

I need an event handler that gets triggered each time any one of a set of registry values is changed.  I want behavior similar to the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class's [Changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx) event, but for registry values.

If there's some other technique I could use to accomplish the same task, I'd appreciate that as well.  My minimum requirement is that it be a better solution than what I have now: polling every 20 seconds and comparing the registry value with the last result.

Please provide example code in your answer.  If I can get an example for watching just one registry value, that would be fine.

I need a solution in .Net 2.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

WMI can sometimes be interesting to work with...I think I understand your question, so take a look at the code snippet below and let me know if it's what you're looking for.

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
// <copyright file="Program.cs" company="">
//   
// </copyright>
// <summary>
//   Defines the WmiChangeEventTester type.
// </summary>
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace WmiExample
{
    using System;
    using System.Management;

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public class WmiChangeEventTester
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WmiChangeEventTester"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public WmiChangeEventTester()
        {
            try
            {
                // Your query goes below; "KeyPath" is the key in the registry that you
                // want to monitor for changes. Make sure you escape the \ character.
                WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery(
                     "SELECT * FROM RegistryValueChangeEvent WHERE " +
                     "Hive = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'" +
                     @"AND KeyPath = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\.NETFramework' AND ValueName='InstallRoot'");

                ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an event...");

                // Set up the delegate that will handle the change event.
                watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(HandleEvent);

                // Start listening for events.
                watcher.Start();

                // Do something while waiting for events. In your application,
                // this would just be continuing business as usual.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000000);

                // Stop listening for events.
                watcher.Stop();
            }
            catch (ManagementException managementException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + managementException.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">
        /// The sender.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="e">
        /// The e.
        /// </param>
        private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received an event.");
            // RegistryKeyChangeEvent occurs here; do something.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Just calls the class above to check for events...
            WmiChangeEventTester receiveEvent = new WmiChangeEventTester();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll try it out and let you know how it works.

Comment: Great, Andrew. Let me know if you have any trouble re-purposing it for your own use. You can ping me on AIM if you want--e4lt0rf3R (replace the numbers with letters). I will be happy to help you resolve any additional questions you have and then post a summary of them here.

Comment: Sorry for commenting an "old" answer, but, is there a way through that example that works for HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Comment: It doesn't tell me exactly _what_ has changed, only that the defined event has triggered. Not quite what a FileSystemWatcher can do.

Comment: Can you give an entire class of registry monitoring? 
It's from here? [RegistryMonitor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC) ?

Comment: @AndrewEnsley I ran this code but how can i trigger this event

Comment: @Ed Altorfer I opened regedit.exe and edited key but event is not triggering

Answer (score 4):

You really don't need WMI, as others have pointed out.  I too have used [RegistryMonitor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/registrymonitor.aspx) with no problems.

If you need an example, there's already example code for the RegistryMonitor on the page itself.  Did you scroll down to this bit on the code project:

```
public class MonitorSample
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        RegistryMonitor monitor = new 
          RegistryMonitor(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, "Environment");
        monitor.RegChanged += new EventHandler(OnRegChanged);
        monitor.Start();

        while(true);

        monitor.Stop();
    }

    private void OnRegChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("registry key has changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did, but... it doesn't meet the requirements of my question. I need example code for an event that gets fired when a specific registry _VALUE_ is changed; not a key. I understand I can get that from RegistryMonitor, but if someone wants to save my time, they have a lot to gain.

Answer (score 3):

Are you limited to WMI?
If not you can use [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/RegNotifyChangeKeyValue.html) wrappers like [RegistryMonitor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC)

Comment: No I am not limited to WMI, that's just the only method I knew of at the time of posting.  Thanks for the links.  They are helpful.  Could you provide some example code though?

Comment: Let's not be rude, guys. The question asked for example code; also, one must bear in mind that some links become stale and example code will be archived here for the foreseeable future. :)

Comment: @Dave short answer, and what no one else has said - yes, he is that lazy.  that's not a bad thing.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi: Read my comment on a similar answer below. The source code and examples given on that project page DO NOT meet the requirements of my question. Registry Monitor only watches for changes to _KEYS_. Any change to any subkeys or values will fire the event handler. I need an event handler for when a registry _VALUE_ changes. Before anyone calls me lazy, they should take the time to actually read the question. /rant

Comment: Like it's been mentioned, the RegistryMonitor link has become stale. The new link for the CodeProject article is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to utilize WMI for it.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393035.aspx

Comment: Ha... I know.  That's the part I need help with.

Comment: I've changed the wording of my question to reflect what I really need.  Any additional help?