# Apply changes in Registry immediately

Tags: firefox, registry

The following code (in a Firefox extension) toggles the value of the "FontSmoothing" Registry-Key.

```
let regFontSmooth = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/windows-registry-key;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowsRegKey);
regFontSmooth.open(regFontSmooth.ROOT_KEY_CURRENT_USER, "Control Panel\\Desktop", regFontSmooth.ACCESS_ALL);
regFontSmooth.writeStringValue("FontSmoothing", regFontSmooth.readStringValue("FontSmoothing") == 0 ? 2 : 0);
regFontSmooth.close();
```

How do I apply the changes immediately (without a reboot or restarting Windows Explorer)?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't? That's not how the windows registry works.

Comment: What do you mean "You don't?"? Can't I do that in Win 7?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567387/c-sharp-how-to-change-windows-registry-and-take-effect-immediately has a more detailed answer.

Comment: The reference to the SystemParametersInfo function is really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks again. I really appreciate it.
This code works:
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
    let lib = ctypes.open("user32.dll");

    let fontSmooth = lib.declare("SystemParametersInfoW", ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.bool, ctypes.unsigned_int, ctypes.unsigned_int, ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.unsigned_int);

    fontSmooth(0x004B, true, ctypes.voidptr_t(0), 0);   // 0x004B = SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING. true/false = toggle font smoothing.

    lib.close();

Comment: Many thanks to Noitidart.

Comment: if you now have working code, with either posting that as answer to your own question, or (if you feel the other question covered everything completely) deleting your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following code toggles Font Smoothing.

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm"); let lib = ctypes.open("user32.dll"); let fontSmooth = lib.declare("SystemParametersInfoW", ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.bool, ctypes.unsigned_int, ctypes.unsigned_int, ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.unsigned_int); fontSmooth(0x004B, true, ctypes.voidptr_t(0), 0); // 0x004B = SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING. true/false = toggle font smoothing. lib.close();
```