# Windows 7 registry: how to edit a registry key by program schedule (batch)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, key

eg. when a specific registry key value becomes 39 i would have to reset it to 0. A batch is possible? Or what app (language) i could use, and how? Can you let me see an example? Thanks

Comment: How soon after the value becomes 39 does it need to be set to 0?  1 seconds, 10 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are a c# developer take a look at this post.  It demonstrates how to monitor a registry value using WMI.  You can then check the return value and if >= 39 set it to 0 .

[Registry Watcher C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826971/registry-watcher-c/849522#849522)

Eample snippet from [Registry Watcher C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826971/registry-watcher-c/849522#849522). Add your registry value change event code here

```
   private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) 
    { 
      RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\My Registry Key", true);
       myKey.SetValue("My Value", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
    }
```