# Best option for background process?

Tags: c#, background-process

I'm about to create a background process and I'm not sure what method i should use, my application will listen out for any new registry startup keys and display to the user whether they accept it or not.
I'm thinking about using a form with no boarders and using the following code:

```
onWaitForm.ActiveForm.BackColor = Color.Transparent
onWaitForm.ActiveForm.Hide();
onWaitForm.ActiveForm.Visible = false;
```

which would make the form invisible, and i would use a Timer to check the registry for any new keys.

Also keeping in mind i wont to keep the applications footprint vary small, so is there any other options i could use maybe like a process that runs in the background and when it detects a registry key it will then open a form?

Comment: You don't need a form, you can simply start a thread watching on the registry. Did you read System.Thread documentation ? Btw, for watching the registry, polling is not the best way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826971/registry-watcher-c-sharp

Comment: Can you please link me to any documentation or a example of a Thread process?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using timer etc use [WqlEventQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.wqleventquery%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) along with ManagementEventWatcher of WMI.