# Windows api registry functions listener

Tags: c#, registry

Is it possible, in c#, to monitor when a certain windows api registry function is triggered and which parameters sent to it ?
for example, I want to know when the function 'RegCreateKeyEx' is been triggered and which parameters it gets, so I can know when a new key is been added to the registry.
can anybody advise ?
thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like `RegistryWatcher` to get notification in case some registry key or value gets updated?

Comment: Are you trying to do this for entertainment purposes (like learn something new and painful) or you just need the result (i.e.  [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) )?

Comment: This requires winapi hooking, not exactly a feature of C#.  The EasyHook library is well known.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in notification of any update in registry key-value pairs.

Windows API provides a function `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`, which notifies the caller about changes to attributes or the content of a specified registry key.

You can read more about it here - [RegistryMonitor - a .NET wrapper class for RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC).

Also [RegistryWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826971/registry-watcher-c-sharp) might be of your help too.