# Registry Watcher C# implement RegistryKeyChangeEvent

Tags: c#, event-handling, registry, windows-xp

OK, I tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30624/Asynchronous-Registry-Notification-Using-Strongly) and watched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826971/registry-watcher-c-sharp). I followed my code-

```
// Construct the query string:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
string queryString = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM RegistryKeyChangeEvent WHERE Hive = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' AND KeyPath = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall' ");

WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery();
query.QueryString = queryString;
query.EventClassName = "RegistryKeyChangeEvent";
query.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
this.Query = query;

this.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(RegistryWatcher_EventArrived);
```

Unfortunately, when I call `Start()` it raise an exception - ManagementException and says **"Unparsable query. "**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some workaround, I found my way to solve it once and for all with ManagementScope instead of WqlEventQuery:

```
ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\default");
EventQuery Query = new EventQuery(@"SELECT * FROM RegistryKeyChangeEvent WHERE Hive='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' AND KeyPath='SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall'");
ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(Scope, Query);
m_watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(RegistryWatcher_EventArrived);
m_watcher.Start();
```

It seems to be something wrong with the way it parse the query, but now its fine.

Comment: when event will trigger?